# I want to filter an array within an array and return every element that meets the criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array were every element (which is a product) has the key "categories", which is an array. I want to get every product that has a category name of "Jolly Rancher"

Here is a small snippet of the json.

```
[
  {
    "id": 7308,
    "name": "JOLLY RANCHER HARD CANDY TROPICAL 368G",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 243, "name": "Brands", "slug": "brands" },
      { "id": 273, "name": "Jolly Rancher", "slug": "jolly-rancher" },
      { "id": 152, "name": "Sweets", "slug": "sweets" }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 7307,
    "name": "HERRS DEEP DISH PIZZA 28.4G",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 243, "name": "Brands", "slug": "brands" },
      { "id": 153, "name": "Crisps", "slug": "crisps" },
      { "id": 268, "name": "Herr's", "slug": "herrs" }
    ],
  },
 {
    "id": 6319,
    "name": "JOLLY RANCHER CANDY 396G",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 243, "name": "Brands", "slug": "brands" },
      { "id": 273, "name": "Jolly Rancher", "slug": "jolly-rancher" },
      { "id": 152, "name": "Sweets", "slug": "sweets" }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
import productsJson from "../data/products.json";

const result = productsJson.filter(product => product.categories);
console.log(result);
```

Which will return everything from the json. This makes sense as it is filtering all the products that have the key "categories which they all do. It is here I am stuck.

If I do the following I will get an empty array.

```
const result = productsJson.filter(product => product.categories.name === "Jolly Rancher");
console.log(result);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `product.categories` is an array and so it doesnt have a `name`. Youll need to loop/filter through the categories to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should search in the categories array like this:

```
const result = productsJson.filter(
       product => product.categories.find(
              category => category.name === "Jolly Rancher"
       )
 );
```

Comment: That's exactly right! That returns the 16 products that I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

because you `categories` is array not object.

```js
const result = productsJson.filter(product => product.categories.filter(category => category.name === "Jolly Rancher"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the category is existed or not using `Array.some` function.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "id": 7308,
    "name": "JOLLY RANCHER HARD CANDY TROPICAL 368G",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 243, "name": "Brands", "slug": "brands" },
      { "id": 273, "name": "Jolly Rancher", "slug": "jolly-rancher" },
      { "id": 152, "name": "Sweets", "slug": "sweets" }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 7307,
    "name": "HERRS DEEP DISH PIZZA 28.4G",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 243, "name": "Brands", "slug": "brands" },
      { "id": 153, "name": "Crisps", "slug": "crisps" },
      { "id": 268, "name": "Herr's", "slug": "herrs" }
    ],
  },
 {
    "id": 6319,
    "name": "JOLLY RANCHER CANDY 396G",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 243, "name": "Brands", "slug": "brands" },
      { "id": 273, "name": "Jolly Rancher", "slug": "jolly-rancher" },
      { "id": 152, "name": "Sweets", "slug": "sweets" }
    ]
  }
];

const result = input.filter(({ categories }) => categories.some(({ name }) => name === 'Jolly Rancher'));
console.log(result);
```